# How do I find the fonts that are not loading in a CORS situation ( MoovWeb )?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, cors, moovweb

I am currently in a situation where I work on proxied websites over the [MoovWeb platform](http://developer.moovweb.com/). Sometimes fonts don't want to load on the proxy because of CORS issues. I know how to get these fonts to load, I simply just need to know *which* fonts are not loading. The console gives me this error

> Font from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'cross-origin-example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I looked at the networks panel, and all I see under the "fonts" section are 4 fonts with a status of 200. Are there any other ways of knowing which font the console is talking about? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer lied in the fact that I was using google chrome. It seems only webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) do not show the font file name. Firefox and IE both show the file that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also use the Moovweb SDK logger to see the messages.
http://developer.moovweb.com/docs/local/debugging

This is a 'browser-free' alternative.

Juan

Comment: Thank you, I have this debugger as a chrome extension, I only use it for tritium logs, but since I usually work in chrome I will probably use this.